# How to upgrade the cocoapod with the specified version?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My issue is how to install the version of 1.4.0 beta 2. 
I have been read the `CocoaPod` website.

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started

I want to update the `CocoaPod`, as the command in the website.

`$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods`

As a result, always install version of 1.3.1

I use this command is incorrect.

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods 1.4.0 beta 2`

Then I ask this question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use this command.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0.beta.2
```

You can check if the version you want is in the sources by using this command.

```
gem search cocoapods --pre
```